# Incorrect syntax near 'Bairstow'. I am getting error on the name of the player which is stored in the sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

```
protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox status = row.Cells[1].FindControl("cb_Cap") as CheckBox;
        //int Credits = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
        string Name = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text);
        if (status.Checked)
        {
            updaterow(Name, "Captain");
        }
        else
        {   
            updaterow(Name, "None");
        }
    }
}

    private void updaterow(string Name, string markstatus)
    {
        string mycon = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-7IGRD5V\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =ULogin; Integrated Security = True";
        string updateData = "Update teamf set role='" + markstatus + "' where Name=" + Name;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lbl_Cap.Text = "Captain Added";
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You missed quotes. You should really be using parameters though

Comment: Can you specify?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue is on your query

```
string updateData = "Update teamf set role='" + markstatus + "' where Name=" + Name;
```

The Name should have quotes. Update your query with single quotes

```
string updateData = $"UPDATE teamf SET role='{markstatus}' WHERE Name='{Name}'";
```

Comment: Yeah. Name is a string and it should be on quotes. Good to use string interpolation here.

Comment: This is still crazy vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Yes it is. Unless he use some sort of prevention that is off topic to this question. I'm not sure if he is using ADO.NET or some ORMs like EF with got inbuilt prevention

Answer (score 5):

It's worse than you know. In the current code, the `con.Close();` line won't run if you have an exception. If this happens often enough you can completely run Sql Server out of connections and effectively lock yourself out of the database.

Even worse still, I can use the `Name` value to run *any arbitrary code I want* on your server, simply by starting my name with `'';`. Imagine if I decided to tell you my name was `'';Drop Table teamf;`. Think carefully about what would happen.

This should fix both those issues, as well as resolve your question:

```
private void updaterow(string Name, string markstatus)
{
    string mycon = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-7IGRD5V\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =ULogin; Integrated Security = True";
    string updateData = "UPDATE teamf SET role= @Role WHERE Name = @Name";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(mycon))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, conn))
    { 
        // Use actual column types and lengths from the database here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = markstatus;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Name;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } //using block will guarantee the connection is closed, *even if an exception is thrown*
    lbl_Cap.Text = "Captain Added";
}
```

Always *always* ***ALWAYS*** use parameters like this to put data into a query! Anything less is practically *begging* to wake up a year from now to find out you were hacked six months ago. If there's any *any other code at all* in the application using string concatenation like this to build SQL, fixing that (because it really is *broken*) is job #1.